# Module Not found Error but it is installed in my environment (jupyter)

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, environment

I have an environment called data science in anaconda. i conda activate this and run jupyter notebook from this AND I change kernel to datascience kernel. I ran a pip install prince since this is the package i want. However when i get the below error:

[image]

I am using windows 10 and the location of my default env is: C:\Users\salwal\anaconda3\envs\datascience. And of course, i have checked that the prince package is actually in there which it is.. What do i need to do to get this to work? Why is it not recognizing that it exists.

[image]

Comment: restart the kernel may be or try !pip install prince in cell

Comment: tried restarting kernel... doesn't work :/ and requirement is already satisified when i run in cell

Comment: have you tried with deactivating environment and again activating environment ??

Comment: tried and it doesn't work

Comment: Post the error diagnostic as text. Unlike text, image cannot easily be searched for.